# Cosa significa "scivolato" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Benedetto parlava con un gentiluomo straniero, uomo di studio o uomo di segreteria, vestito di panno rosato schietto. Era costui di statura e di persona non sovrabbondanti, di testa piccola, di viso stretto dal mento lievemente **scivolato**.

Questa descrizione fa riferimento a Niccolò Machiavelli. Ho cercato "scivolare" e "scivolato" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il significato di "scivolato" in questo passaggio. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Può essere un sinonimo di "mento sfuggente"?

Answer (score 1):

Il ***mento scivolato*** fa riferimento ad un viso in cui la posizione  del mento rispetto alla proporzione dei vari elementi che compongono il viso si discosta da un certo canone di (passami il termine) normalità oppure simmetria, quasi che sia visto attraverso uno specchio deformante.

L'espressione è riportata in un interessante passaggio nel volume [L'arte di leggere di Guido Conti](https://books.google.it/books?id=AuswBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=mento%20scivolato&source=bl&ots=iF5uCcNjXu&sig=7SsBMhiv2N1lO_s-y6pu70YivWY&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1u5fb5O_VAhXIPhQKHS8hDUIQ6AEIPTAH#v=onepage&q=mento%20scivolato&f=false) dove si legge un estratto da un racconto di Čechov del 1883:

> Ripulii sommariamente lo specchio e mi ci guardai, scoppiando a
>   ridere. Un'eco rispose cupa al mio riso. Era un o specchio deformante,
>   la mia faccia ne risultava sotto ogni aspetto distorta: il naso sulla
>   guancia sinistra, il ***mento scivolato*** da una parte, e diviso in
>   due.

Comment: A parte che personalmente non sono sicuro che sia questo il senso nel contesto della Bellonci, la citazione non viene da Carroll, ma da un racconto di Čechov (ma non riesco a vedere quale perché Google Books non mi fa vedere abbastanza pagine: qualcuno ci riesce?), o per meglio dire dalla sua traduzione italiana. Quindi sappiamo solo che un imprecisato traduttore di Čechov ha usato questa espressione.

Comment: Giusto, correggo la citazione.

Comment: Nella pagina di it.wiki possiamo vedere un ritratto di Machiavelli: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccolò_Machiavelli. Non mi sembra che il mento sia "fuori simmetria"…